# iOS background image resolution: How to support all iOS devices

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, react-native

We need to set background images that supports all iOS devices including recently launched devices like iPhone 12 and 12 Pro Max.

Right now we are using following resolutions images for background images.

- 640x1136 -> @2x
- 750x1334 -> @2x
- 1242x2208 -> @3x
- 1080x1920 -> @3x

Is there any naming convention that we need to follow to support all the devices?

I found apple documentation in which all resolutions are mentioned with specific devices which we can use.
https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/

In Assets.xcassets how to set @2x and @3x images because there are multiple @2x and @3x images based on the different screen resolutions.

Comment: The system won't automatically select an image from a set of images based on the screen size; If you want that, you would need to write the code yourself.  A simpler approach is to have a single image and set the content mode to `.aspectFill`; There will be cropping on some devices but you don't need to maintain an ever growing list of images and code to select it as Apple releases new devices.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and review [ask]. This post is outside the scope here - it's a **design** question, not a **programming** question. A couple comments though... App **design** is about more than different size images. You want to think about how your *entire* app UI will look on different devices / screen sizes, and design a layout that will **adapt** properly.

Answer (score 1):

Use vector images. Apple does not support SVG so your best option is to use PDF. You can then use .aspectFill or any other settings to scale the image to diffrent devices as you see fit.

After importing the files into Assets you want to check the "Preserve as Vector" box.

[image]